# log4j is not able to print MDC key-value pair in threads

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, mdc

I am setting key-value pair as `MDC.put("txnId", UUID.randomUUID().toString());` with log4j.properties as

```
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}]  [%m] [%M] [%L] [%p] [%c] [%X{txnId}] %n
```

This works absolutely fine while logging the non-threaded logs, but the logs of classes which `implements Runnable`, txnId is coming as empty.

Below is the thread code

```
public class ConsT implements Runnable{
    public ConsT() {

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            log.info("Start thread"));
    }
```

I have tried putting my values in both `org.apache.log4j.MDC` and `org.slf4j.MDC` but none works.

Answer (score 2):

This problem nothing to do with the `Runnable` instance. MDC must be set per-thread basis as it uses a [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) internally to remember the values.

If you are using [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) directly or [`ExecutoService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html.) you must ensure that MDC value is set directly before your `Runnable` runs. If you use a thread pool it also must be cleared after the `Runnable` finishes.

There are many ways to achieve it but one possible way is to define a wrapper class:

```
class MDCWrapper implements Runnable {

  private final Runnable target;

  @Override
  public void run() {
    MDC.put("txnId", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    try {
      target.run();
    } finally {
      MDC.remove("txnId");
    }
  } 

}
```

and then use it as:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new MDCWrapper(new DeviceEventWorker()));
t.start();
```

Comment: That's some on-target explanation.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

pass the current txnId as parameter in constructor when you create a new DeviceEventWorker

```
new DeviceEventWorker(.... , MDC.get("txnId"));
```

and set again in run method

```
public class DeviceEventWorker implements Runnable{

    private String txnId;

    public DeviceEventWorker(String tenantId, DeviceResource device, String eventName, LighthouseDevice lighthouseDevice, String txnId) {
            this.tenantId = tenantId;
            this.device = device;
            this.eventName = eventName;
            this.lighthouseDevice = lighthouseDevice;
            this.txnId = txnId;    
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            MDC.put("txnId", this.txnId);
            log.info("Start thread"));
    }
...
}
```